# RASA NLU: Can't extract entity

Tags: rasa-nlu

I've trained my rasa nlu model in a way that It recognizes the content in between square brackets as **pst** entity. For the training part, I had covered both the scenarios with more than 50 examples.

---

There are two scenarios(only space difference):

1. When I pass `http://www.google.comm, 1283923, [9283911,9309212,9283238]`, it is considering only `[` bracket as the pst entity.
2. When I pass `http://www.google.comm, 1283923, [9283911, 9309212, 9283238]`, it is working fine and recognizing `[9283911, 9309212, 9283238]` as the pst entity as expected.

---

For the scenario 1, I've tried all the possible pipelines, but it only recognizes the first square bracket [ as the pst entity

In the response, I am getting this output:

```
{
  'intent': {
    'name': None,
    'confidence': 0.0
  },
  'entities': [
    {
      'start': 0,
      'end': 22,
      'value': 'http://www.google.comm',
      'entity': 'url',
      'confidence': 0.8052099168500071,
      'extractor': 'ner_crf'
    },
    {
      'start': 24,
      'end': 31,
      'value': '1283923',
      'entity': 'defect_id',
      'confidence': 0.8334249141074151,
      'extractor': 'ner_crf'
    },
    {
      'start': 33,
      'end': 34,
      'value': '[',
      'entity': 'pst',
      'confidence': 0.5615805162522188,
      'extractor': 'ner_crf'
    }
  ],
  'intent_ranking': [],
  'text': 'http://www.google.comm, 1283923, [9283911,9309212,9283238]'
}
```

---

So, Can anyone tell me what I am missing in the configuration? The problem is happening because of spacing only, and my model should have the knowledge of spacing as I am providing the training data with both scenarios.

Comment: What pipeline, specifically, what tokenizer generated the above? What makes you think you need NLP rather than just a regex pattern matcher?

Comment: I am running nlu for different intents and entities too, so I want to use only rasa nlu for this project.

Comment: I am using spacy_sklearn pipeline only. should I use any other piepline for extraction?

Answer (score 0):

It is good idea to use Regex for your purpose. Rasa NLU supports extraction of Entities by Regex. Normal NLU training data will have something like below

```
{
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
    "common_examples": [
    {
        "text": "Hi",
        "intent": "greet",
        "entities": []
     }]
    } 
}
```

You can provide Regex data for training as below in the NLU json file.

```
{
    "rasa_nlu_data": {
        "regex_features": [
            {
                "name": "pst",
                "pattern": "\[..*\]"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Reference: [Regular Expression in Rasal NLU](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/docs/dataformat.rst#regular-expression-features)

Comment: I've tried this solution, but unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference in the output.

Comment: Don't know what it the use of this, because it is mentioned in the rasa nlu docs that this regex won't change anything in the output.